# Which is the opposite of this action?Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function:

**CODE JS:**

```
$('#add_new_rec').click(function (e) {
    // custom handling here
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#input_sending_div').append('<div id="container-rec"><div class="row"><div class=" col-md-12"><label for="clg_firstname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="clg[\'fistname\'][]" id="clg_firstname[]"></div></div><div class="row"><div class=" col-md-12"><label for="clg_middlename">Middle Initial</label><input type="text" name="clg[\'middlename\'][]" id="clg_middlename[]"></div></div><div class="row"><div class=" col-md-12"><label for="clg_lastname">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="clg[\'lastname\'][]" id="clg_lastname"></div> </div><div class="row"><div class=" col-md-12"><label for="clg_phone">Phone Number</label><input type="text" name="clg[\'phone\'][]" id="clg_phone"></div></div><div clas="row"><div class=" col-md-12" id="last-input"><label for="clg_email">Email</label><input type="text" name="clg[\'email\'][]" id="clg_email"></div></div></div>');

});
```

**CODE HTML:**

```
 <p id="add_new_rec" >
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" ></i>
                    <span>Add new recipient</span>

 </p>
```

I want to know which is the opposite of this action in jQuery?
Use it function remove?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of having opposite of it:

with `.empty()`:

```
$('#input_sending_div').empty(); // to clear the contents
```

with `.html()`:

```
$('#input_sending_div').html(''); // to clear the contents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove()` for that https://api.jquery.com/remove/.

```
$("#input_sending_div").remove("#container-rec");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use remove api in jQuery

```
$('#container-rec').remove();
```